# How to allow hyphen in kendo numerictextbox?

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

```
(function ($) {         
      $("#numeric").kendoNumericTextBox({
        format: "-"
      });           
    }
```

Unable to add hyphen in the middle of the text box

Comment: Why you need - in Numeric text box? It will allow only the number format specified in this link: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/numberformatting

Comment: i would like to enter a value in the textbox as below "000-12341234" and  it should not allow any characters

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to use `kendoMaskedTextBox`

```
$("#mytextbox").kendoMaskedTextBox({
                        mask: "000-00000000"
                    });
```